# Android icon displays in application list but is transparent on home screen

Tags: android, homescreen

I've created an Android application and deployed it to my Samsung Galaxy S. The application icon (PNG file) displays fine when installing the application and when viewing the application list (the list displayed when clicking on the Applications icon from the home screen). However, when I add the application to my home screen, the icon is completely invisible (transparent). I can only see the application title below the transparent icon.

I initially edited the icon in GIMP 2.6.8 and exported it as PNG files of 36x36, 48x48 and 72x72 for the res/drawable-ldpi, res/drawable-mdpi and res/drawable-hdpi directories respectively. I subsequently tried opening and saving it in GIMP 2.6.11 to see if that would make a difference. I even had a friend import and re-save it in PhotoShop, also to see if that would make any difference.

One last bit of information, when I open my icons in MS Paint they're either completely black or in the case if the PhotoShop ones, black with a white border. However the stock Android icons display normally (except for the fact that they're not transparent).

Frankly, I'm stumped. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: PS When I drag the icon onto the home screen, I can see the icon in the draggable outline/shadow. Sames goes for when I drag it to the trash bin at the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that the PNG files you *save as* or *save a copy* in Photoshop have display issues, but when you use Photoshop's *save for web* function and enable transparency that the icons work correctly. I have NO clue why *save as* produces a different file and I'm not sure what the options to do this in GIMP would look like but you might want to try that and see if it fixes your issue.